# React Native / redux-form Unable typing Korean (compisite character)

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-form

This bug still happens when I put Korean characters.  breaks character composition.

[image]
[https://photos.google.com/search/*tra*/photo/AF1QipMngnr-dee4TVgmJfKDvoqJSSmXO3w69FhIR0GT](https://photos.google.com/search/_tra_/photo/AF1QipMngnr-dee4TVgmJfKDvoqJSSmXO3w69FhIR0GT)

***(Deck Title : `가ㄱㅏㄱㅏ` should be `가가가`)***

In korean, to input charater '가', I have to enter 'ㄱ' and then 'ㅏ', and they are composed into '가'
But, when value changed to non-empty value from empty value, it breaks a composition. So I can't enter '가' to the TextField

It looks `ReduxForm` has a bug.
because normal `TextInput` element or `tcomb-native` works well.
I think ReduxForm re-rendering is breaking the composition.

Could you let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: The image you tried to insert is not there

Answer (score 1):

This is a widely-reported bug that Facebook introduced sometime around 0.55. The pull request to fix the issue has been merged, and is included in 0.58.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/19809